# EmberJS : Translation using i18n library is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

My project need to support 3 different languages. We used Emberjs for development.

So for implementation of  translation , I followed the tutorial provided in the following URL

http://eviltrout.com/2013/11/24/i18n-in-ember.html

I have included the i18n.js from the following url

https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/i18n.js

into my project Then i created a file named translation.js with contents of

```
I18n.translations = {
  en: {
    savingquote: 'savings made simple'

  },

  hi: {
    savingquote: 'बचत सरल बनाया'        
  },
  es : {
  savingquote:'ahorros de forma sencilla'

  }  
};
```

And in my project am view page am referring it as  `{{i18n  savingquote}}`  . And added a helper to my app.js with following code

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('i18n', function(property, options) {
  var params = options.hash,
      self = this;

  // Support variable interpolation for our string
  Object.keys(params).forEach(function (key) {
    params[key] = Em.Handlebars.get(self, params[key], options);
  });

  return I18n.t(property, params);
});
```

Now my requirement is to change language of my project without reloading .  So in my language change function  am adding `I18n.locale = 'hi';` . But handlebars appearing in default language english.

Your comments are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not necessary to reload the page but you will need to refresh/rerender the active ember `view` since translations are not meant to be bound properties.

*DISCLAIMER: have not used the specific implementation, but have implemented a similar functionality supporting ember apps (in code and templates) and html parts (out of templates).*